# Setting Up A Windows 2008 NPS Server As A Radius Server For A Cisco AP541N Cluster

Tags: windows-server-2008, cisco, radius

I have a cluster of Cisco AP541N access points.  I am trying to use the Radius authentication for WPA-Enterprise authentication, but I cannot get the APs to query the server properly.

Does anyone know of a cookbook or recipe for setting up the NPS server to provide authorization?

My current configuration is as follows.

The APs are simple, they just have a Radius Server IP field and a Radius Secret field.  The SSID has all the options set: WPA, WPA2, Enable pre-authentication, TKIP, CCMP(AES) and Use Global Radius Server Settings.

On the server, each AP is defined as a client, each with a unique friendly name (cap-1 through cap-3).  The secret is the same as on the AP cluster.  Each AP is defined as a Cisco, and has the *Access-Request Messages must have the Message-Authenticator Set* box checked.

There is a single Network Policy, set as:

- policy enabled
- grant access
- unspecified network access server

Conditions:

- Windows Group Membership (a user group)

Constraints:

- Auth methods: EAP PEAP and EAP-MSCHAPv2; MS-CHAP-v2; MS-CHAP; CHAP; PAP/SPAP

Settings:

- all Standard Attributes have been removed (the PPP framing type etc).

When I try to connect to the AP, the AP logs:

```
 cap-4th-2 hostapd: wlan0vap2: RADIUS Possible issue with RADIUS server connection - no reply received for first three attempts
```

Around the same time, the Windows server logs:

```
NPS: 18: An Access-Request message was received from RADIUS client 10.17.15.247 with a Message-Authenticator attribute that is not valid.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

**On the AP541N:**

Set the Global Radius settings:

- Radius server IP
- Radius secret

Set the SSID to connect to by selecting all:

- WPA
- WPA2
- Enable pre-authentication
- TKIP
- CCMP (AES)
- Use global RADIUS server settings

**NPS Pre-configuration:**

The role to install is Network Policy and Access Services, the service is Network Policy Server.

Once it is installed, right-click on NPS (local) and select Register Server In Active Directory.

(Also note that I usually have to stop and then start the NPS Service after running through the below configuration the first time; future changes seem to take effect right away.)

Define the RADIUS clients: Server Manager -> Roles -> Network Policy and Access -> NPS (Local) -> Radius Clients -> Radius Clients

Create a new client:

- Make sure it is enabled
- Short, friendly name
- IP address or DNS name
- Manual shared secret
- Repeat this set up for each AP in the cluster.

**Define the Connection Request Policy:**

Under Connection Request Policy, create a new policy. On the overview tab:

- make sure it is enabled
- the type of network access server is Unspecified

On the Conditions tab:

- Client Friendly Name, set to soemthing which matches the Client Friendly Names you set above; for example, I have cap-1, cap-2, and cap-3, so my Client Friendly Name in the connection policy is cap-*

On the Settings tab, Authentication methods:

- select Override network policy authentication settings
- Add EAP Types EAP-MSCHAP-v2 and PEAP
- select MS-CHAP-v2
- select MS-CHAP
- leave all the other boxes unselected

You shouldn't need any other values.

**Define the Network Policy:**

On the Overview tab:

- make sure it is enabled
- Grant access
- clear Ignore user account dial-in properties
- Type of network access server is Unspecified

On the Conditions tab:

- Windows Groups: set to the windows user group that will grant access
- Client Friendly Name: same as the connection policy above

On the Constraints tab:

- leave everything as default; but ideally it should look the same as the connection policy above

On the settings tab:

- remove the Standard Radius Attributes (PPP Framing type etc) because you don't need them

**Configure Domain Clients:**

Wireless Properties:

- Connect automatically

Security tab:

- WPA2-Enterprise
- AES
- PEAP
- Remember my credentials

PEAP Settings:

- clear Validate Server Certificate
- Select Authentication Method: EAP-MSCHAP-v2
- Enable Fast Reconnect

Security tab, Advanced Settings:

- Specify authentication mode: user authentication

**Configure Non-Domain Windows Clients:**

As above, except:

EAP-MSCHAP-v2 Configure:

- clear Automatically Use my Windows logon name and password (and domain if any)

**Further Refinements**

I added a second Network Access policy that permits access to computers that are members of a particular group.

I then changed the Security Tab -> Advanced Settings -> Specifiy Authentication Mode to Computer authentication.

Finally a co-worker created a GPO that pushes out a pre-defined SSID network definition with the settings above to all domain member computers.

Now all domain laptops automatically connect to the wireless.

Non-domain member computers can still join as long as the Specify Authentication Mode is set to User authentication.

Configuring tablets, phones, and non-Windows computers is left as an exercise for the reader.

(Further updates to this will appear on my wiki page at http://wiki.xdroop.com/space/Windows/Server/2008/Radius+Server+for+Cisco+AP541N )

Comment: Alternatively, set the WiFi network as a GPO.  This eliminates local configuration errors, which is the biggest problem to this solution.